# PHP: How to instantiate a class from a property 'className'

Tags: php

Imagine this code:

```php
class MyClass
{
    private string $className;
    public function __construct(string $className)
    {
        $this->className = $className;
    }

    public function instantiateClass()
    {
        $className = $this->className;
        return new $className();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to instantiate the class without first assigning the property value to the local variable `$className` in method `instantiateClass()`?

Something like this:

```php
class MyClass
{
    private string $className;
    public function __construct(string $className)
    {
        $this->className = $className;
    }

    public function instantiateClass()
    {
        // This cannot be done as 'className' should be a method, not the property
        return new $this->className();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [The way you did it](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6d84dba2b4db2a86a67043bfe6278fad34619c2)

Comment: @Cid, yes, it works! I supposed it hadn't, but it does! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So, as pointed out by @Cid in the comments below my question, the solution is actually the one I thought was wrong:

class MyClass
{
private string $className;
public function __construct(string $className)
{
$this->className = $className;
}

```
public function instantiateClass()
{
    // This works! It doesn't find a method, but reads the property correctly!
    return new $this->className();
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

you can use `__CLASS__` or  `self::` or `static::`

you can try

```
class MyClass
{

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    static public function instantiateClass()
    {
        return new self();
    }

    static public function instantiateClassWithStatic()
    {
        return new static();
    }

}

$myInstance = MyClass::instantiateClass();
```

Comment: `$className` is another class.